# Find vector and parametric equations of the line passing through the given point and perpendicular to the given plane.

Tags: analytic-geometry

*Analytical Geometry of Space – Equation of Line*

**Question**:
Find vector equation, parametric equations of the line passing through the point $(5,1,0)$ and perpendicular to the plane $2x-y+z=1$. Also find two other points on the line.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have been given a point and a direction, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

**Equation of a Line Through a Point and Perpendicular to a Plane**

The equation of a line passing through the point $\, P_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)\,$ perpendicular to a plane given by the equation $\, Ax+By+Cz+D=0\,$ or by $\, \vec{r}\vec{N}+D=0\,$ is
$\dfrac{x-x_1}{A}=\dfrac{y-y_1}{B}=\dfrac{z-z_1}{C}\,$ (in component form), and

$(\vec{r} - \vec{r_1}) \times \vec{N} = \vec{0}\, $ in vector form.

Once you have a line, it is trivial to find any other two points on it...